# how JSBridge works in React-Native

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, webview

When I'm building **hybrid web app** (have the web page in a **webview, wrapped in a native app**). I use the `scheme://functionName/functionParameters` trick to allow Javascript sending "commands" to native code. Either by creating an `"<iframe src = URL/>` or calling `window.location = URL`. Then on iOS & Android side, I intercept all HTTP requests, and check if that URL starts with the `scheme://` we specified, then execute that function.

Question is, what **trick** does **React-Native** use to allow JS talk to native and vice-versa? Do they use the same `scheme` method? Please explain it in a bigger picture, the mechanism they use.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native you write [native modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) that can be used from JS.

You write JS wrapper (either API or UI component), and then implement native code for (both) platforms using RN conventions.

**Update more on JS bridge**: RN definitely don't use any `scheme` url as it is not running in web-view. It communicates over RN JS bridge that sends asynchronous events in both directions.

[image: JS Bridge]

This communication is used for both your custom native modules as well as for RN itself.

And here is more official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html) about the topic.

Comment: OP asks for the underlying mechanism used for JS-native code communication. Since JS and native code run on separated isolated environment, how do they exactly send data between each other?

Comment: @sodik why people say passing over the bridge is expensive and should be minimized, **what exactly** makes passing data via bridge **slow**?

Comment: I believe 2 things: it is asynchronous and you have to serialize data between JS and native world (ios or android). And well, it is relatively slow, for most usecases it is more then fine, but that's why RN is working on declarative animations so that they are smooth (if you need to update each 16ms, it might be laggy).

Answer (score 0):

```
NativeModules.SharefPreference.getMpin((mpin)=>console.log(mpin))
```

Above is the Function used in React Native to include a native module for Android for more detailed info see [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-native-modules-in-react-native-android-hybrid-apps-62b67a2cc7ca).